# Cant buy new, download or update existing purchased free apps from cloud via iTunes 12.3.0.4?

Tags: ios, itunes, applications, ios-appstore

For more than 48 hours, my computer has not been able to download apps - purchase or download updates. I see no error messages, but in the background there are no downloads at all?

My account seems OK as I can download on my iPad & iPhone with iOS 9.0.2

Why is iTunes 12.3.0.4 on Windows 8.1/PC not allowing me to buy & download free apps or update/ download existing purchases from cloud?

Answer (score 1):

The help article has several options - these are the ones you can check:

1. Set the date/time on your PC to match an internet time server
2. Check anti-virus / firewall software on the PC
3. Sign out of the app store on iTunes and then sign back in

Barring that, you might need to get at the debug or error logs for the App Store - http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/store/ or AppleCare can help. Maybe someone else can edit in where the logs are on a PC.

Comment: Did all 3 already. Hasnt helped. 

Apple care people are Not Geniuses, I know where the logs are, How do I deciper and fix?

Comment: @AlexS  I only have knowledge of UNIX/Mac logs - You might edit your question or ask a follow on question laser focused to "where does iTunes XYZ log app store attempts and failures on Windows 8.1"? - If I knew I'd post, but I'd have to call Apple Support myself to find that answer. I see nothing while STFW with the above text. Well, one person suggested c:\Program Files (x86) and copy QTMovieWin.dll from within Commn Files to iTunes folder... but I can't vouch for that at all.

Comment: @AlexS Also, if you go the support route, When you call AppleCare, your goal is to be organized enough that in 5 minutes the person helping you concludes you have done all the obvious fixes they have been trained to try and have them conclude to kick "your can" up to level 2, level 3 or engineering. You don't need a genius to handle most support calls, so it's not staffed that way.