# Copy Apps from iPad to PC iOS 9

Tags: itunes, backup, ios

I have lots of apps on my iPad and I want to copy them to my PC, usually I'd just click transfer purchased in iTunes but now it's not working. I want to backup and restore my iPad because I've been having some issues. iFunBox isn't working either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfer purchases was actually disabled in iOS 9. Apple disabled it because there are many different variants of an app from the App Store. This means that an app that was on an iPad Air that was then transferred to a PC can't be used on an iPhone or an iPad Mini.

A thread was posted [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206544/cant-transfer-purchases-from-iphone-to-itunes-in-ios-9) about why it was disabled and goes into more detail.

If you want to put all your data onto a new iPad, just backup your old iPad and restore as a backup on a new iPad.

Good luck!

Cheers

Comment: Apparently it's cause Apple is doing App Thinning, but that feature was delayed so i thought theyd still let you transfer apps to itunes.