# How do I manually install an app in iTunes 12.7?

Tags: itunes, applications, install

I foolishly installed iTunes 12.7, and now find that I am unable to install a development/QA version of my company's app for testing.  After downloading the IPA, I am following the steps found on [Apple's support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201593), under "Manually add items from your computer."

There, I'm told to drag the IPA file to the iTunes sidebar, like so:

> [image: Apple's instructions for dragging an IPA file to the iTunes sidebar to install it]

But when I do exactly that, it tries to create a shortcut, and fails (the section of the sidebar blinks several times):

> [image: Nothing happens when I drag the app; just shows "link" text]

This is in iTunes 12.7, to an iPad mini 4, iOS 10.3.3.  Manual management is enabled:

> [image: Manually manage music and videos option is checked]

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298391/how-do-i-download-an-ios-app-ipa-file-to-my-mac-after-itunes-12-7-update/298455#comment377196_298455

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the Apple Configurator 2?

I just read about it here, but haven't actually tried it myself:
[How do I download an iOS App (IPA) file to my Mac after iTunes 12.7 update?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298391/how-do-i-download-an-ios-app-ipa-file-to-my-mac-after-itunes-12-7-update)

Here's a description from the above link:
http://krypted.com/apple-configurator/upgrade-devices-and-apps-using-apple-configurator-2/

Comment: As of the latest iTunes where the Apps section was removed, this is now the official way of managing them even for unsupervised devices.

Answer (score 2):

you're dragging into the wrong place, click on the phone icon on top and then drag it under "On My Device"

Comment: Check with new iTune version 12.7 apple has removed App option from connected device.

Answer (score 2):

You can download an older version of iTunes from Apple [Here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208079)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you're familiar with [Cydia Impactor](http://www.cydiaimpactor.com/). If you're not, Cydia Impactor is a software that allows you to put any IPA inside of any Apple device (iPhone or iPad). Of course you need an Apple ID to do so.

There are plenty of videos on the internet that shows you how to do so. But if you need any help feel free to ask anything.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks; I'll check it out.  I'd much prefer a mechanism supported by Apple though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to install a new version of **iTunes** just drag your ipa file to your device in **iTunes** and drop, **Drag and drop** will do the magic for you and you will get your app install in seconds.