# How can I extract audio files from an app?

Tags: ios, ipad, audio

Is there any way I can extract audio files from an iOS app?  Would jailbreaking be required?

This would be relatively easy on Android, but I cannot figure out how to get the app onto a PC.

The reason I want to do this is simply because I have an iPad app that has some very nice alert sounds, which I would like to use for my desktop alert sounds, phone notifications and terminal bell (personal use only).

Comment: Well you need to gain access to the app package on your Mac (or PC) and i Believe that iMazing will allow you to transfer your apps to your Mac (or PC). After that it would be up to you to figure out how the sounds are encoded in the app. Note that access to the app package doesn't guarantee access to *everything* in the app.

Comment: @SteveChambers Thanks, I have installed iMazing, but I cannot find any way to export .ipa files.

Comment: That would be a question you ask iMazing support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Apple Configurator 2 to update the app on your iOS device, but before disconnecting the iOS device, copy the iOS app out of the Configurator's temporary directory.  See:

[How do I download an iOS App (IPA) file to my Mac after iTunes 12.7 update?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298391/how-do-i-download-an-ios-app-ipa-file-to-my-mac-after-itunes-12-7-update/298882#298882)

for how to find this directory.  If the media assets of an app are not encrypted or obfuscated, you can sometimes find them by unzipping the .ipa file.